# Why this form is still submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am really tired of this form i was trying to prevent it from submitting for a time that i can not remember!

I am trying to prevent the form from submitting if the validation is not true, I believe that it's submitting when it is looking for file codes.txt

Please anyone tell me how can i submit it only after my validations are correct?

Help me stack overflow! you are my last hope.

```js
        $('form').submit(function() {
            var errors = 0;
            $("form input[required]").map(function(){
                if( !$(this).val() ) {
                    errors++;
                }
            });

            $("form textarea[required]").map(function(){
                if( !$(this).val() ) {
                    errors++;
                }
            });

            if(errors > 0){
                alert("You must fill out the required fields");
                return false;
            }

            if(!$('#terms-checkbox').is(':checked')) {
                alert('You must accept the terms and conditions');
                return false;
            } else {
                if ($.trim($('#code').val()).length == 0){
                    alert("You must enter code");
                } else {
                    $.get('codes.txt', function (contents) {
                        if (contents.includes($('#code').val())) {
                            validForm =true;
                        } else {
                            alert("Sorry!! That is not a valid code.");
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">var validForm=false;</script>
    <iframe name="hidden_iframe" id="hidden_iframe" style="display:none;" onload="if(validForm) {window.location='confirmation-page.html'}"></iframe>


    <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdC9Jr65fCIhRLiSXzVRoDKJAB8was3LoyN0DaCVrVLRa-nJg/formResponse" target="hidden_iframe" method="post">


<!--Some Inputs goes here-->

        <input id="terms-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="aaaa" value="Bike"> <span style="color: red;font-size: 14px;">*</span> I have read and agree to the above terms and conditions

        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="form-control btn-default" >

    </form>
```

Comment: `$.get` is async, the rest of your code keeps running while the request is processing.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Do you mean that it's who causes the submission?

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Check this fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taL0moao/1/)